# Using a private member function in the class

Tags: c++, class, private-members

So I have this class:

The purpose of this class is to change the post fix algebraic expression (1234*+-) to infix expression (1*2+3-4).

```
    class PostfixExpression
    {
    private:
        string postfix;
        vector<string> tokenizedEx;
        double result;

        void tokenizeStr(); // Where do I call this?

    public:
        PostfixExpression(string p);    
        //mutators, and accessors for string and double only
        //no accessor and mutator for vectors
        string changeToInfix() const;
    };
    PostfixExpression::PostfixExpression(string p)
    {
        setPost(p);
    }
   //mutators, and accessors
   void PostfixExpression::tokenizeStr() 
    {

        stringstream ss(postfix);
        tokenizedEx.clear();
        string hold;
        int i = 0;
        while (ss >> hold)
        {
            tokenizedEx.push_back(hold);
        }
    }
    //....
```

The purpose of the private class `tokenizeStr()` is to tokenizing the string and put it into the `vector<string> tokenizedEx`.

For example, in my main, I would have

```
int main()
{
     PostfixExpression test("1 2 3 4 * + -");
}
```

Now I am trying to tokenize the string and update it to the `vector<string> tokenizedEx` via the private member function `tokenizeStr()`.

After tokenized, each element in the vector should either contain an integer or an operator, but I can't seem to find a way to call the function.

I know it is totally illegal to call private member functions from main since the function is private.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a changeToInfix() method in your class which you haven't shown the implementation of. That method should be the one calling tokenizeStr().

Comment: I skipped changeToInfix() because the code kinda long to post. But when I tried to call tokenizeStr(), it has the following error:
error C2662: 'PostfixExpression::tokenizeStr' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const PostfixExpression' to 'PostfixExpression &'

Comment: I figure it is because the changeToInfix() function is a const so I can't call the private member function

Comment: A function with "change" in the name probably shouldn't be const, for obvious reasons.  But if you're really sure you want that function to be const, you can also declare tokenizedEx as mutable.

Comment: Yea i kinda have to because it is one of the requirements. Could you elaborate of declaring tokenizedEx as mutable?

Comment: That gets into "bitwise const" vs "logical const", which isn't hard per se, but it might be a bit more advanced than this assignment is intended to be.  I'd go with invoking it in the constructor for now.  But when you're interested, http://writebettercode.org/2006/05/discussion-topic-1-logical-vs-bitwise.html looks like a decent self-contained introduction.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I am on that advanced level yet. And thanks for mentioning the changeToInfix() method because now I realized a fatal mistake at this method. I will make this one the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your setPost method does what? Setting the postfix member?

You can call tokenizeStr() in the constructor, right after calling setPost.

Comment: the setPost is the mutator for the string postfix. Also, I have tried to put it in the constructor but it doesn't seem to work as the vector is still empty

Comment: The vector probably should be empty since you haven't put any tokens in it yet. What's the actual error you encountered?

Comment: Turns out it was stupid on my part. The vector was actually filled with but I did not use the correct method to check if it was empty or not.